# Delphi (Indy + ADO) CoInitialize Slow

Tags: delphi, indy

I am trying to get each connection thread in a TIdTCPServer instance to instanciate a TADOConnection into the context.

This works fine, and I place the CoInitialize(nil) in the OnConnect event handler. Problem is it takes around 20-25 seconds for this process to work, which is WAY to long...

Any advice?

Cheers,
Adrian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very unlikely that either `CoInitialize()` or ADO takes that long to initialize.  I have worked with multithreaded COM for years and never experienced such a delay.

That being said, a better place to initialize COM is at the top of the calling thread's `Execute()` method rather than in the server's `OnConnect` event.  To do that with Indy, derive a new class from `TIdThreadWithTask` and override its `BeforeExecute()` and `AfterExecute()` methods.  Then instantiate a `TIdSchedulerOfThread...` component, assign your class to its `ThreadClass` property, and assign it to the server's `Scheduler` property before activating the server.

Comment: thanks so much for that; you are right, I misdiagnosed the culprit. It's this line:

        TC2CContextdata(AContext.Data).ADOConnector := TADOConnection.Create(nil);


Where the left side is the TIdContext typecast. Why would this be soo slow?

Comment: All of this is on the OnConnect event of the server.

Comment: That is not what I asked. How do you know that `TADOConnection.Create()` is taking 20+ seconds to run? How are you timing it? Are you using a profiler, like AQTime? Are you counting CPU ticks? Are you using a performance counter?